# Sport Cards Task

Tags: c#, performance, programming-challenge

> ## The task:
>
> You will receive several input lines in one of the following formats:
>
> - `"{card} - {sport} - {price}"`
> - `"check {card}"`
>
> The card and sport are
>   strings. Price will be a floating point number. You need to keep track
>   of every card.  When you receive a card,  a sport and a price,
>   register the card in the database if it isn't present, otherwise add
>   the sport and the price. If the card already contains the sport, you
>   need to overwrite the price. If you receive `"check {card}"` you need to
>   check if the card is available or not and print it on the console in
>   the format:
>
> `"{card} is available!"` if the card is present and
>
> `"{card} is not available!"` if the card is not present
>
> You should end your program when you receive the command `"end"`. At that point you should print the cards, ordered by sports’ count in desecending order. Foreach card print their sport and price ordered by sports’ name.

### [Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dKfr.png)

#### My Solution

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    class Card
    {
        public Card(string n, string s, double p)
        {
            name = n;
            addSport(s, p);
        }
        public void addSport(string sportName, double price)
        {
            if (sportPriceInfo.ContainsKey(sportName))
            {
                sportPriceInfo[sportName] = price;
            }
            else
            {
                sportCount++;
                sportPriceInfo.Add(sportName, price);
            }
        }
        public string name;
        public int sportCount = 0;
        Dictionary<string, double> sportPriceInfo = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        public void showInfo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name + ':');
            var sortedDictionary = from pair in sportPriceInfo
                                   orderby pair.Key ascending
                                   select pair;
            foreach (var item in sortedDictionary)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  -{0} - {1:0.00}", item.Key, item.Value);
            }
        }
    }
    class Database
    {
        List<Card> allCards = new List<Card>();
        public void addCard(string n, string s, double p)
        {
            int cardIndex = isCardPresent(n);
            if (cardIndex >= 0)
            {
                allCards[cardIndex].addSport(s, p);
            }
            else
            {
                allCards.Add(new Card(n, s, p));
            }
        }
        public void checkCard(string n)
        {
            if (isCardPresent(n) >= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(n + " is available!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(n + " is not available!");
            }
        }
        private int isCardPresent(string n)
        {
            //returns the index of the matched item, otherwise returns -1
            int cardIndex = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < allCards.Count; i++)
            {
                if (allCards[i].name == n)
                {
                    cardIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return cardIndex;
        }
        public void showDataBase()
        {
            List<Card> sortedCards = allCards.OrderByDescending(o => o.sportCount).ToList();
            foreach (var card in sortedCards)
            {
                card.showInfo();
            }
        }
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        string line;
        Database db = new Database();
        Match lineSplit;
        while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != "end")
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^(\w+) - (\w+) - (\d+.\d+)\b$"))
            {
                lineSplit = Regex.Match(line, @"^(\w+) - (\w+) - (\d+.\d+)\b$");
                string inputName = lineSplit.Groups[1].Value;
                string inputSport = lineSplit.Groups[2].Value;
                double inputPrice = double.Parse(lineSplit.Groups[3].Value);
                db.addCard(inputName, inputSport, inputPrice);
            }
            else
            {
                lineSplit = Regex.Match(line, @"^check (\w+)\b$");
                db.checkCard(lineSplit.Groups[1].Value);
            }
        }
        db.showDataBase();
    }
}
```

Comment: Give your code a bit of breathing room. It's a bit difficult to see where elements begin and end. Microsoft has guidelines: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions#layout-conventions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
>   public void addSport(string sportName, double price)
>   {
>      ...
> ```

and

> ```
>   public string name;
> ```

In general the convention in C# is that all public members are named with PascalCase:

```
public void AddSport(..)
```

and

```
public string Name;
```

Where private members or local variables are named with camelCase:

```
private int sportCount = 0;
```

---

> ```
>   public int sportCount = 0;
> ```

Counting the sports with a separate variable is unnecessary and error prone. Instead rely on the `Count` member of the `sportPriceInfo` `Dictionary`:

```
public int Count => sportPriceInfo.Count;
```

---

> ```
>   public void showInfo()
>   {
>     Console.WriteLine(name + ':');
>     var sortedDictionary = from pair in sportPriceInfo
>                            orderby pair.Key ascending
>                            select pair;
>     foreach (var item in sortedDictionary)
>     {
>       Console.WriteLine("  -{0} - {1:0.00}", item.Key, item.Value);
>     }
>   }
> ```

In general avoid writing to the console from your model. If you want a model class to be able to write itself then inject a delegate with the appropriate signature:

```
public delegate void LineWriter(string format, params object[] parameters);
```

and use it like this:

```
  public void showInfo(LineWriter lineWriter)
  {
    lineWriter("{0}: ", name);
    var sortedDictionary = from pair in sportPriceInfo
                           orderby pair.Key ascending
                           select pair;
    foreach (var item in sortedDictionary)
    {
      lineWriter("  -{0} - {1:0.00}", item.Key, item.Value);
    }
  }
```

The you can call the method like:

```
card.showInfo(Console.WriteLine);
```

It is more flexible this way, if you for instance want to write to a log or use `Debug.WriteLine`

---

> ```
>   public void addSport(string sportName, double price)
>   {
>     if (sportPriceInfo.ContainsKey(sportName))
>     {
>       sportPriceInfo[sportName] = price;
>     }
>     else
>     {
>       sportCount++;
>       sportPriceInfo.Add(sportName, price);
>     }
>   }
> ```

Here the rule says that a second sport with the same name replaces an existing one, so no need to search for it:

```
public void addSport(string sportName, double price)
{
  sportPriceInfo[sportName] = price;
}
```

this will either replace or add the new sport.

---

> ```
> class Database
> {
>   List<Card> allCards = new List<Card>();
> ```

Instead of a `List<Card>` I would use a `Dictionary<string, Card>` instance as collection for the cards. It will make the maintenance easier:

```
  public void addCard(string n, string s, double p)
  {
    if (!allCards.TryGetValue(n, out Card card))
    {
       card = new Card(n, s, p);
       allCards[n] = card;
     }
     else
     {
       card.addSport(s, p);
     }
```

or

```
  public bool checkCard(string n) => allCards.ContainsKey(n); // see below
```

---

BTW: avoid using abbreviated names for method arguments. Instead of `n`, `s` and `p` - `name`, `sport` and `price` would be more informative. Remember that arguments are the "interface" that a consumer must rely on - without necessarily knowing about the objects internal behavior.

Again: the name `allCards` is too "verbose". Why not just `cards`?

---

> ```
>   public void checkCard(string n)
>   {
>     if (isCardPresent(n) >= 0)
>     {
>       Console.WriteLine(n + " is available!");
>     }
>     else
>     {
>       Console.WriteLine(n + " is not available!");
>     }
>   }
> ```

Here again: don't write to the console from your models. Instead return a flag and let the client react accordingly to that:

```
public bool HasCard(string name) => allCards.ContainsKey.(name); // If using a dictionary instead of a list.
```

---

> ```
>     if (Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^(\w+) - (\w+) - (\d+.\d+)\b$"))
>     {
>       lineSplit = Regex.Match(line, @"^(\w+) - (\w+) - (\d+.\d+)\b$");
> ```

Here you parse the string two times with the same pattern. It is unnecessary because you can use the `Success` property of the returned `Match` object from `Regex.Match()`:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(line, @"^(\w+) - (\w+) - (\d+.\d+)\b$");

if (match.Success)
{
  ...
}
```

---

About the pattern `@"^(\w+) - (\w+) - (\d+.\d+)\b$"`:

It doesn't catch names with two or more words or with hyphens or the like.

And if you take a careful look at the input examples in the image, you'll see that the hyphens aren't of equal length, so you'll have to handle both dashes and hyphens.

All in all that could be done with a pattern like:

```
@"^(?<card>.+) [-–] (?<sport>.+) [-–] (?<price>\d+.\d+)$"
```

Here I also name the subexpressions so it is possible to query the `match` object like:

```
      string inputName = lineSplit.Groups["card"].Value;
      string inputSport = lineSplit.Groups["sport"].Value;
      double inputPrice = double.Parse(lineSplit.Groups["price"].Value);
```

---

> `double.Parse(lineSplit.Groups["price"].Value)`

When you parse a numeric string you'll have to consider the current locale. So if the input number always uses `'.'` as decimal separator, you should parse with a `IFormatProvider` argument:

```
double.Parse(lineSplit.Groups["price"].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Otherwise the parser may interpret the price differently, if the current culture for instance uses `','` as separator.

If the price is in an invalid format, `double.Parse` will fail with an exception. You should handle that in a `try...catch` block, or use `double.TryParse(...)` instead and handle a false return from that appropriately.

---

When it comes to prices and currency, it is by the way common to use the `decimal` type instead of `double`.

---

When I try your method with the two provided input examples it prints `" is not available!"` near the top in both examples?